# Using `Seq::fill` with an existing sequence

Tags: scala

I would want to fill a `Seq[Seq[Int]]` instance with an existing `Seq[Int]` by using the method `fill(n1, n2)(element : A)` of the Object `Seq`, as detailed in the documentation : http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/Seq$.html#fillA(elem:=>A):CC[CC[A]]

So I wrote this call :

`Seq.fill(width, width)(_random_values.)` , with `_random_values` the existing `Seq[Int]`.

The problem is that the parameter of the second list of `fill` is an element, not a `Seq`. So, what could I type to iterate on each `_random_values`'s integers AND to execute the `Seq.fill` for each current integer ?

Comment: if you have a `Seq(1,2,3)` what would be the desired outcome?

Comment: If I have `width` = 2 and a `Seq(1, 2, 3, 4)`, my outcome would be `Seq(Seq(1, 2) , Seq(3, 4))`. (NB : `width` = "dimension")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Seq.fill` is more appropriate to create a `Seq` base on a static value. For your use case `Seq.grouped` might be a better fit:

```
val values: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

val result: Seq[Seq[Int]] = values.grouped(2).toSeq

result.foreach(println)

/*
List(1, 2)
List(3, 4)
*/
```

Comment: Mmmh the result is the same but I really want a `Seq[Seq[Int]]`, not an `Iterator`